# C - Users belonging to the group - Linux

Tags: c, linux, administration, ansi-c

I tried to solve display all users who belong to the group specified as a parameter(optarg).

I wrote first case which shows all users and below it their groups, and now I want create b case with parameter optarg containing the name of the group.

I can't use gr_mem because I'm not a root.

```
struct passwd *p;
gid_t *groups = NULL;
int ng = 0;
struct group *gr;


int i, opt;

while((opt = getopt (argc, argv, "a")) != -1){
    switch(opt){
        case 'a':
            setpwent();
                while ((p=getpwent()) != NULL){
                    printf("%s\n", p->pw_name);

                    if(getgrouplist(p->pw_name, p->pw_gid, groups, &ng) < 0){
                        groups = (gid_t*) malloc(ng * sizeof (gid_t));
                        getgrouplist(p->pw_name, p->pw_gid, groups, &ng);
                    }

                    for(i = 0; i<ng; i++){              
                        gr = getgrgid(groups[i]);
                        printf("%s\n", gr->gr_name);
                    }   
                }   
            endpwent();
        return 0;
    }
}

setpwent();
while ((p=getpwent()) != NULL)
    printf("%s\n", p->pw_name);
endpwent();
```

Answer (score 0):

> I can't use gr_mem because I'm not a root.

You need not be a root to use the field `gr_mem` of `struct group`.